# Access to the d pointer from PySide

Tags: python, qt, pyside

I'm trying to create some custom widgets using PySide which will extend existing widgets.  Is it possible to get access to the data stored in the "d pointer" from PySide.  For example I would like to subclass QLabel.  I need to write a new paintEvent function, however, I will need to duplicate some of the paintEvent code that uses data from the "d pointer" such as d->control->document(), which as far as I can tell QLabel has no member function to retrieve that.  Is this possible to do purely with Python or do I have to create a c++ subclass and create new Python bindings for it?

Edit in response to comment by @f.rodrigues (because my response is too long for a comment)

The main thing I needed to do here was create a vertical label, where the text was rotated 90 degrees.  There are plenty examples on StackOverflow (and the rest of the web) about how to create this by subclassing QLabel and overriding the paintEvent function.  The issue here is that now the paintEvent of my new class is called, not the QLabel paint event.  So any functionality from the QLabel.paintEvent that I want to have in the subclass must be rewritten in the subclass.  If you look at the source code for QLabel::paintEvent there are some code paths that can be taken that are impossible without using the d pointer.  If I was writing a c++ program the answer would be to simply use the d pointer in the subclass' paintEvent.

For my immediate need I was able to get what I needed without using the d pointer.  I would like to know the answer to my question in case I need to modify my VerticalLabel class or have a need to subclass a different Qt class.

Comment: Why do you need the d pointer? What do you want to do? I'm asking this because it seem that this question is clearly is XY problem ( http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378 )